# Customize Logitech M600 mouse in Fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, mouse

I just got a fancy Logitech M600 touch mouse, and there are very specific things I want it to do on my Fedora 20 64-bit KDE spin. Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any config files where I can just state my demands. I've been looking for a few days now, and have determined that touchegg and HIDPoint are completely out of the question (on account of having absolutely no support for F20).

By default, it has middle-touch vertical scrolling, two-finger vertical scrolling, left-swipe is browser back, right-swipe is browser forward.

I need left and right swipe to cycle through virtual desktops, *two*-finger swipes (not natively a gesture at all) to be browser forward and back, and it'd be nifty if three-finger down swipe was minimize or alt+tab.

On Windows, this can actually be done easily with Logitech's software, but of course they don't have a Linux version. I'd be happy to edit config files and remap input manually if necessary, but without that additional software the mouse has no idea that half the gestures I want are even significant.

I'm hoping someone here has a solution. If not, I can thankfully return the mouse.